# Simple C program. String returning from function causes Error

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, return

The following is the exercise 10.4 of the book Programming in C, by Stephen Kochan. It says that I should create a function, that derives a part from an input string and returns that part back to `main()` (as a string, not a pointer) and displays it.
My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char subString (const char source[], int start, int count, char result[count + 1] ){ //result will be number of characters (count) + 1 (because of null)
int i, j, end = start + count;

// the part excluded must start from i = start and "count" number of characters must be derived and then put on result
for( i = start, j = 0; i < end; ++i, ++j)
    result[j] = source[i];

result[j] = '\0';

return result[count + 1];
}

int main (void){
char result[20] = {0};

const char text1[] = "character";

result[20] = subString( text1, 4, 3, result );
printf("From \"%s\" this part is being excluded-> \"%s\"\n", text1, result);

return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
From "character" this part is being excluded-> "act"

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.332 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Notice that the code above runs perfectly well - no warnings.

What i can't understand is when i replace the two lines below

```
result[20] = subString( text1, 4, 3, result );
printf("From \"%s\" this part is being excluded-> \"%s\"\n", text1, result);
```

with this line

```
printf("From \"%s\" this part is being excluded-> \"%s\"\n", text1, subString( text1, 4, 3, result ) );
```

i get the output:

```
From "character" this part is being excluded-> "(null)"

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.332 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Why is that? How can i make it work using that one line instead? 
Also, I'm a little confused with functions returning strings/arrays. They tend to lead me on errors, so if someone could provide me a couple of suggestions, that i should always keep in mind when working with them, that would help me very much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is no valid element called `result[20]`. Hint: `0` based index.

Comment: You might need to sanity-check the parameters and ensure that start+count doesn't go out of bounds of the source string. And the loop should be de-obfuscated into this: `for(i = 0; i<count; i++) result[i] = source[i+start];`

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I initialized the string with 20 places in memory and put a null in it, because someone told me here a while ago, that  i should always filling null terminators in them when i initialize them (regardless of size) since that's good programming practice.

Comment: @Lundin yes you're right, that would make things easier.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra Please see my answer. I'm taking about the 21st element, which does not exist. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1 :**

In First case, you are using the `result` value which got modified through being passed as argument to `subString()`. You're **not using the return value** of `subString ()` fucntion.

OTOH, in second approach, you're **trying to use the rerturn value** of the `subString ()` function, that too using wrong format specifier. You can learn more about the correct format specifiers in the [man page of `printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

**Point 2**

Array index in `C` starts from `0`. So, there is no valid element called `result[20]`. Thus,

```
result[20] = subString( text1, 4, 3, result );
```

cause off-by-one error which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: ..ah i see (about point 2). Yes i know these. Yes i didn't mean to put it on 21st element. I thought that this was the right way to type the array and store inside the string i want. I'm still looking into this. I haven't understood completely. And yes, point 1 very true, didn't realize that. But still i want to figure out how to return string from function (and not pointer). Still looking..

Comment: @RestlessC0bra yeah Please look carefully. Double check the data types, return values and format specifiers always. :-)

Comment: @RestlessC0bra what do you mean by `eturn string from function (and not pointer).`? what is the _represenation_ of a _string_? You locate and use a _string_ by the _base address_ which is a pointer itself. Then?

Comment: Yes, yes but i'm talking about using string terminology (strictly a string) and not use pointers. I know that in essence a string is a pointer. Since this exercise was in the book before pointers were presented, it's asking me to do it without using pointers.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("From \"%s\" this part is being excluded-> \"%s\"\n", text1, subString( text1, 4, 3, result ) );
```

Make a note that `subString()` returns a character not a `char*` and you are using `%s` to print a character which will lead to undefined behavior.

Your array is being modified in the function `subString()` and in the first case you print the array result by returning `result[count + 1]` and also there is a undefined behavior with

```
result[20] = subString( text1, 4, 3, result );
```

> Array out of bound access

You need to modify your code like

```
char *subString (const char source[], int start, int count, char result[]){ //result will be number of characters (count) + 1 (because of null)
int i, j, end = start + count;

// the part excluded must start from i = start and "count" number of characters must be derived and then put on result
for( i = start, j = 0; i < end; ++i, ++j)
    result[j] = source[i];

result[j] = '\0';

return result;
}

int main()
{
  // Keep your array here
  char *p = subString( text1, 4, 3, result );
  printf("%s\n",p);
}
```

or

```
void subString (const char source[], int start, int count, char result[]){ //result will be number of characters (count) + 1 (because of null)
    int i, j, end = start + count;

    // the part excluded must start from i = start and "count" number of characters must be derived and then put on result
    for( i = start, j = 0; i < end; ++i, ++j)
        result[j] = source[i];

    result[j] = '\0';

    }
```

In `main()`

```
printf("%s\n",result);
```